# How to say "To do someone's work"?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

How to say "To do someone's work"?

For example, if I'm doing my sister's homework, because she's not feeling well. How do I say it?

Answer (score 3):

The most direct translation would be simply "to do someone's work for them."  In your example, "I'm doing my sister's homework for her".

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do someone's work because he or she is not available, I think there is a phrasal verb with similar meaning:

**[Stand in:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stand-in_1) to do someone else’s job temporarily while they are not available to do it**

> Lorraine was ready to stand in if Helen got sick.
>
> I’ll be standing in **for** Peter while he’s away.

Comment: Usually - at least as far as I've seen - this term is used when talking about a job or occupation (as the definition above says).  Doing homework isn't a job, so this wouldn't be used for that case, however, it works perfectly fine with occupations!

Comment: @keitereth24 Homework was an example. look at the title: How to say “To do someone's work”?

Comment: It's a clarifying comment, not a criticism. To know about the phrase "to stand in" is great, and it's also helpful to know to not use it with that particular example. :) However, what you said does indeed answer the question they asked.

Comment: @keitereth24 You are absolutely right bro. I didn't take it as "criticism". However, I do not have any problem with criticisms.